# Sort an array with multiple columns and multiple keys in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I want to create a function that can sort an array with multiple columns (and multiple Ascending/Descending keys).
This function needs to be dynamic (even on the cost of performance).

This function should have 3 parameters:

1. The 2 dimensions array we want to sort.
2. An array of the "columns key" numbers we want to sort.
3. An boolean array that True = Ascending and False = Descending

In the end this function should return the sorted array.

For example:

```
Dim SortedArray as Variant

SortedArray = MySuperSortArrayFnc(MyArr, Array(4,1,7), Array(True, False, False))
```

MyArr = My 2 dimensions source array that i want to sort.

Array(4,1,7) = the order/levels of the sorting.

Array(True, False, False) = it should be parallel to the previous array parameter, so column 4 is ascending, column 1 is descending and column 7 is descending.

Notes:

1. The function cant allow to use a worksheet, it should be pure VBA logic.
2. No need to handle a single array column scenario, only multiple columns array.
3. No need to handle validation on the input(parameters) like if the "MyArr" paramter is not empty.
4. Empty values or any other value should be sort order like the excel sort order, if the excel send the empty value to bottom, its fine by me.

Comment: Can you not just wrap the sort function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort ?

Comment: @JohnnieL - No, it should be sort function without any use of excel object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, if anyone needs it in the future, here is the code:

```
Public Function SortArr2DM(Arr2D As Variant, aColArr As Variant, IsAscendingArr As Variant) As Variant
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim X As Byte
'
Dim aCol As Long
Dim TmpValue As Variant
Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim IsSwitch As Boolean
Dim IsAscending As Boolean


tmpArr = Arr2D


For I = LBound(tmpArr) To UBound(tmpArr)
    For J = I + 1 To UBound(tmpArr)
    
        For X = 0 To UBound(aColArr)
            aCol = aColArr(X)
            IsAscending = IsAscendingArr(X)
            
            If IsAscending Then
                If tmpArr(I, aCol) > tmpArr(J, aCol) Then
                    IsSwitch = True
                    Exit For
                ElseIf tmpArr(I, aCol) < tmpArr(J, aCol) Then
                    IsSwitch = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
                If tmpArr(I, aCol) < tmpArr(J, aCol) Then
                    IsSwitch = True
                    Exit For
                ElseIf tmpArr(I, aCol) > tmpArr(J, aCol) Then
                    IsSwitch = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
                
        Next
        
        If IsSwitch Then
            For C = LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2)
                TmpValue = tmpArr(I, C)
                tmpArr(I, C) = tmpArr(J, C)
                tmpArr(J, C) = TmpValue
            Next
            IsSwitch = False
        End If
        
    Next
Next
    
SortArr2DM = tmpArr
End Function
```